# Updating JQuery dataTable table outside itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I managed to get jquery datatables plugin to work with asp.net mvc 3 so it posts back json, and with a search function.

Problem now I that I need to move the search box and add a "language" filter outside it's "normal" position next to a custom made menu.

Is there a way that I can integrate:

```
Language: <select name="languageid">
<option value="SV">Swedish</option>
<option value="EN">English</option>
</select>
Keywords: <input type="text" name="keywords">
```

To refresh datatables when languageid or keywords change? and still have sorting, paging working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My brain is only firing at half power today, but the short answer is that this can be done; it's just my suggestions that are kind of vague...sorry!

- There are a whole set of language options in oLanguage; it was a bit "Too Long, Didn't Read" for me to sort through, but perhaps something there will help you identify where to set up a language switcher
- You can remove the search box from the main table and set up your own, using the fnFilter method to trigger the search
- Depending on how your other options are configured (server-side, for example), there are methods to trigger a refresh of the table. You would bind a listener for the languageid or keyword change action (`.on('change', '#languageid', function(e) { /* ... */ })`) which would fire the appropriate refresh action (in my instance which uses server-side, I use `fnDraw()`)

I'm sorry about the directionless advice, but I wanted you to know at least that this is possible. Posting the question on the datatables.net forums directly might get you the best possible answer.

Comment: my brain is not firing as well so I'll check it out after 4 weeks of vacation starting monday :) thx for giving pointers, I might bother you later next month if I struggle still :)